# Can usage of C++ references be considered giving a function parameter a new name?

Tags: c++, eigen

I was taught that giving concrete names to function parameters improves readability however what should I do if the function is an implementation of some mathematical formula where variable names are single letters by convention?

Is what I have done in the example a correct approach?

```
void EKF::update(const Vector& innovation, const Matrix& innovationCovariance, const Matrix& measurementObservationJacobian) {
    const Vector& y = innovation;
    const Matrix& S = innovationCovariance;
    const Matrix& H = measurementObservationJacobian;

    const Vector K = P * H.transpose() * S.invert();
    /* More temporary variables and calcuations follow */
}
```

Edit: Add a more concrete example based on [KF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Predict)

Comment: Nothing technically wrong with what you've done, but whether it is an improvement will depend very much on the audience.

Comment: You'll also need to be aware of aliasing rules.  You could trigger undefined behavior without even realizing it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Surely it's safe as long as the new variables have the same types as the parameters?  It may break certain optimizations, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge exactly, the aliasing rules were put into place to allow optimizations.  But once you've invoked UB the compiler is not obligated to produce sane output no matter what your optimization settings are.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Sure, but I can't see how any example similar to OP's (where the types are the same) could result in undefined behavior.  "Strict aliasing" isn't in play here. I'm thinking of a case where the compiler may know that the original parameters don't alias each other (as with an extension similar to C's `restrict`), but isn't able to figure out that the local references don't alias either, and therefore has to generate inefficient (yet correct) code that assumes they might alias.  Instead of "break optimizations" I should have said "prevent optimizations".

Comment: Why would the idiomatic variable names from the mathematical formula not be suitable as the "concrete" names too? I think a more realistic example than `elaborate_name1` might help clarify the question.

Comment: I would use `y`, `S` and `H` as function parameters, they are short, but very concrete (and easily readable) if you know the convention. Maybe some general documentation about the used convention may be useful if your users don't use the same convention.

Comment: @MarkRansom Where's the potential UB here?

Comment: @JonathanWakely I edited the question to be more concrete, note that not everyone follows the EKF letter convention

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I'm not an expert on the aliasing rules, but I thought that violating them invoked UB.  And I'm not sure the example posted here has a problem, but I thought it was an important thing to be aware of for anyone considering this approach.

Comment: @MarkRansom It would, but why would the aliasing rules be violated by this pattern? I can't see it getting near violating them, off the top of my head. You'd need a powerful cast like `reinterpret_cast` (or a C-style cast) to achieve that, which is by design.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings any time you have two variables referring to the same object, that's aliasing.  As I said I'm not an expert, it's a situation I try to avoid whenever possible because I hate being accidentally wrong.

Comment: @MarkRansom Okay. I guess you also never pass by reference then? ;)

Comment: @MarkRansom you get UB when you _break_ the type based aliasing rules by accessing an object through an lvalue of the wrong type. Simply creating a reference or pointer that aliases another object is completely fine. Put another way, aliasing _violations_ cause UB, aliasing doesn't.

Comment: "as long as the new variables have the same types" is solvable by AAA - almost always auto. Example: `const auto &y = innovation;`. However, if the formula pronumerals were well known, like `F = ma` or `s = ut +1/2 at^2`, I'd just use the short names. If you're looking to modify function, (or even use it), you probably should learn the formulae.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the idea, but I don't see why it's preferable to just using the right names and documenting the interface properly. For example, using Doxygen syntax:

```cpp
/** Update function for Extended Kalman Filter
 *
 * @param y  Innovation or measurement pre-fit residual
 * @param S  Innovation (or pre-fit residual) covariance
 * @param H  Measurement observation Jacobian (matrix of partial derivatives)
 *
 * More complete description here, blah blah.
 */
void EKF::update(const Vector& y, const Matrix& S, const Matrix& H) {
    const Vector K = P * H.transpose() * S.invert();
    /* More temporary variables and calcuations follow */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing "wrong" with what you've done.

This is actually a good use of references: your function parameter names are descriptive and self-documenting (presumably), but then you also clearly map these to existing terminology from another domain. That makes your expression easy to read (presumably), and shouldn't cost you anything in terms of performance or maintainability.

It's also very similar to how you'd write the algorithm out in "real life". You start by listing the one-character variables and explaining what they are; then you use them in a formula. So, if your intention is to stick to the original algorithmic form, this is a great way to put it in your code.

And, yes, it could be described as giving a function parameter a new name. That's generally what references do: introduce a new name for a pre-existing thing.

Do note, however, that how acceptable this pattern is will be completely subjective, and if you're employing it in many places in your project, you may raise a few eyebrows.

Also, if these single-letter names are *completely* conventional, and your target audience are all going to be domain experts forevermore, you may find that the original short names, despite being unclear in the programming sense, are actually easier for your readers to quickly understand at the callsite and in your interface documentation, than longer names that you've made up yourself.

Comment: Your answer summarizes my inner thoughts. I would definitely go for the single letter parameter names if all of us used the same convention (which is not the case). As it stands I'm trying to figure out what other, more experienced developers would do.

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński Well, to summarise, for what it's worth I'd do exactly what you have (and good work with all the `const` and formatting!). But you and I are just two people. :)